# Get application full path in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if there is a best way or best practice to get the full path of application in Node.js. Example: I have a a module in sub folder **/apps/myapp/data/models/mymodel.js**, and I would like to get the full path of the app (not full path of the file), which will return me **/apps/myapp**, how do I do that? I know **_*dirname*** or **_file** is only relative to the file itself but not the full path of the app.

Comment: I found my own answer: path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's probably a better solution, **BUT** this should work:

```
var path = require('path');

// find the first module to be loaded
var topModule = module;

while(topModule.parent)
  topModule = topModule.parent;

var appDir = path.dirname(topModule.filename);
console.log(appDir);
```

**EDIT**: Andreas proposed a better solution in the comments:

```
path.dirname(require.main.filename)
```

**EDIT**: another solution by Nam Nguyen

```
path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)
```

Comment: woo.. I did not expect that complicated but I will try that and thanks.

Comment: `path.dirname(require.main.filename)` should do the exact same thing. Note that this (as well as OP's) solution will fail if you run the app through another app (pm2, forever or mocha being common cases).

Comment: If you want to turn this into a function, and put it in a single place (say `common.js`), there will be a problem: you need to know the location of `common.js` (relative to the current file) so that you can use `require('common.js')`. Actually `__dirname` will never solve the problem nicely. I think in nodejs apps, files are supposed to know *where they are*, and there's simply no need for the root path.

Comment: yeup, console.log(require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)); works. Thanks ALL!

Comment: I also found out another solution: require('path').dirname(process.mainModule.filename)

Comment: @AndreasHultgren, look like path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename) solution might be safer instead of require.main.filename if we run the app through another app? I'm not sure though and wondering if you have any thought.

Comment: Indeed it seems more supervisor-proof, but it still would fail with eg mocha (or other testing frameworks). Then I realize that might not be a problem since I guess one can override process.mainModule in the tests?

Comment: I'm not sure either if it will be the issue, we only know when we test it :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me..  With supervisor running the app from a different dir.

```
require('path').dirname(Object.keys(require.cache)[0])
```

example..  files:
/desktop/ya/node.js

```
  require('./ya2/submodule')();
```

/desktop/ya/ya2/submodule.js

```
module.exports = function(){
    console.log(require('path').dirname(Object.keys(require.cache)[0]))
}

$ node node.js  
       => /desktop/ya

$ (from /desktop) supervisor ya/node.js
       => /desktop/ya
```

Comment: I also found another solution: require('path').dirname(process.mainModule.filename)