# Get absolute URL path using Node Js Express and possibly ajax

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, url, absolute-path

I am relatively new to Node.JS and have been reading a lot about the topic. However I am at an impasse. I am trying to get the absolute path of a file:

Example:
**https://localhost:8080.../public/img/apple.jpg**

Instead I am only getting nothing printed back in console or just the usual:

**/public/img,apple.jpg**

Below are is my JavaScript file I run in node. I have tried a few things, however I believe these are probably the closest.

Note: I have tried a lot inside 'app.get' function but it never seems to print out to the console.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var req = require('request')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var path = require('path');

   app.get('../img/apple.jp', function(req, res) {
      var dir = req.params.dir;
      console.log(req.originalUrl)

      var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.originalUrl;

      console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
      console.log("test" + fullUrl);

      // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'sliderImages.json'));
      var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
      console.log(fullUrl);
});
```

Some of the following links I have went to are as followed:

1. https://nodejs.org/api/path.html
2. [Get application full path in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620270/get-application-full-path-in-node-js)
3. [How do I get the path to the current script with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-to-get-path-to-current-script-with-node-js)
4. [How to get the full url in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express)

I have went into others as well but I believe these are the closest from what I have read. Especially number 4.

Comment: Did you try `path.resolve`? https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/path.html#path.resolve

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot the `g` in `../img/apple.jp`.
- You have required `http`
  twice.
- You have a `req` object in your app.get but you use `request`
  instead. (be careful with copy/past of other's code)

Comment: Sorry unfortunetly that's not the problem, I made the fix and still nothing. I will update on here shortly

Comment: Alright so I figured out what was the problem I had app.get inside of httpCreateServer. Had to take it out and have on a seperate port. The only problem now is im not sure the path I give it for finding a file in app.get(file

Comment: @l1ghtk3ira : maybe you should consider using [express.static()](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was (for beginners) that app.get needs to have it's ***own*** port. I was trying it inside http.CreateServer because you think you created it now do things inside it. However it seems it requires to be outside and have its own port for making a call.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require("http");

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var req = require('request')
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   contents = fs.readFileSync("sliderImages.json", "utf8");

   response.end(contents);
}).listen(8080);

app.get('sliderImages.json', function(req, res) {
    var dir = req.params.dir;
    console.log(req.originalUrl)
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.originalUrl;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    console.log("test" + fullUrl);

    var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    console.log(fullUrl);

    res.send(url.parse(req.url).pathname);

});

app.listen(3000);
```